# Centering a map with javascript

Tags: centering, overscroll

I have a website where I use some javascript to "scroll" a map. 
This works great only I can't get the map to center on pageload.

What I need is to center it

The script I'm using called overscroll which is on Github: 
https://github.com/azoff/Overscroll/blob/master/jquery.overscroll.js

On line 582 i think it need to be changed:

```
    position: 'absolute',
    opacity: options.persistThumbs ? settings.thumbOpacity : 0,
    'background-color': 'black',
    width: size.width + 'px',
    height: size.height + 'px',
    'border-radius': size.corner + 'px',
    'margin': size.top + 'px 0 0 ' + size.left + 'px',
    'z-index': options.zIndex
```

(only need the left centering).

So I think this:
'margin': size.top + 'px 0 0 ' + size.left + 'px',

Needs to be something like:
'margin': size.top + 'px 0 0 ' + size.left + 'px' : 2 - half size.left ??

I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

What about getting the client's screen width and make the proper calculation?

```
'margin': size.top + 'px 0 0 ' + (screen.width - size.width) / 2 + 'px',
```

may be?

Comment: I finally managed to fix this. Placed some other centering script onto an image into the div. Your script might be rite but didn't do anything, anyway thank you for your reply!